# custom configuration for a mathjax-latex installation

Tags: plugin-mathjax

I'm experimenting with a bitnami wordpress service on an amazon hosted VM, and have installed the mathjax-latex plugin.  This works when I configure it to use the 'Use MathJax CDN Service', but I'd like to have some of my own macros.

Per the readme, I put a copy of the MathJax tree under plugins/mathjax-latex/MathJax:

```
wget https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/zipball/v2.3-latest
mv v2.3-latest ~/tmp/mathjax-v2.3-latest.zip
unzip ~/tmp/mathjax-v2.3-latest.zip
mv mathjax-MathJax-78ea6af MathJax
```

so that it sits here:

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/mathjax-latex/MathJax
```

Under 'Custom MathJax location, if you are not using the CDN' in the mathjax-latex plugin configuration I have tried all of:

```
/wp-content/plugins/mathjax-latex/MathJax/default.js
/wp-content/plugins/mathjax-latex/MathJax
http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/mathjax-latex/MathJax
http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/mathjax-latex/MathJax/default.js
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/mathjax-latex/MathJax/default.js
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/mathjax-latex/MathJax
```

with default selected under 'MathJax Configuration', but my downloaded version of MathJax fails to load when I access a page with some mathjax markup.

I presume that I'm specifying the 'Custom MathJax location' incorrectly.  Anybody know how to properly specify this, or if anything else is required to install my own customized mathjax configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It required the actual dns name, and MathJax.js as the filename:

```
http://ec2-[...].compute-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/plugins/mathjax-latex/MathJax/MathJax.js
```

Requiring the dns name is unfortunate since that changes each time if I stop and later reactivate the VM.